how to solve improper integral
$$\int^{a}_{l}\frac{a^3 - x^3}{(a^2 - x^2)^{3/2}} {\rm d}x$$
I have obviously separated the integrals into
$$\int^{a}_{l}\frac{a^3}{(a^2 - x^2)^{3/2}} {\rm d}x$$
$$\int^{a}_{l}\frac{- x^3}{(a^2 - x^2)^{3/2}} {\rm d}x$$
For the first integral I can solve the integral by substituting $u=u_0 \sin \theta$ whereas for the second integral substituting $a^2 - x^2 = t$ helps. But I am not quite sure how to actually get the answer for the improper integral as the results blow up at $x=a$. Solving with Mathematica gives the expected answer
$$\frac{(2a+l)\sqrt{a^2 - l^2}}{a+l}$$

Separating as you have done will not work, as the integrand in each part is on the order of $(x-a)^{-3/2}$ near $x = a$ (unless $a = 0$).

What @arkeet said.  Writing a convergent integral as the difference of two divergent integrals will not help.

Instead of separating them, I'd let $x=a\sin(\theta)$ which gives
$$\int \frac{a^3-a^3\sin^3(\theta)}{(a^2-a^2\sin^2(\theta))^{3/2}}a\cos(\theta)d\theta = \int\frac{a^3(1-\sin^3(\theta))}{a^3(1-\sin^2(\theta))^{3/2}}a\cos(\theta)d\theta$$
$$= a\int\frac{1-\sin^3(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta = a\int\Bigg(\sec^2(\theta)-\frac{\sin^3(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}\Bigg)d\theta$$
$$=a\int\sec^2(\theta)d\theta-a\int\frac{\sin^3(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta = a\tan(\theta)-a\int\frac{\sin(\theta)(1-\cos^2(\theta))}{\cos^2(\theta)}d\theta$$
Making the substitution $u=\cos(\theta)$, we get
$$=a\tan(\theta)+a\int\frac{1-u^2}{u^2}du = a\tan(\theta)+a\int(u^{-2}-1)du = a\tan(\theta)+a\bigg(-\frac{1}{u}-u\bigg)$$
$$=a\Bigg(\tan(\theta)-\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}-\cos(\theta)\Bigg) = a\Bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}\Bigg)$$
$$=a\Bigg(\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}\Bigg)$$
This is our antiderivative. Now plug in $a$ and $\ell$ and subtract. Plugging in $a$ (or more precisely, letting $x\to a$ and using l'Hospital's Rule on the first term), we get 0. Subtracting the expression with $\ell$ plugged in then gives
$$a\Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}}{a}-\frac{\ell-a}{\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}}\Bigg) = \sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}-\frac{a(\ell-a)}{\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}} = \frac{a^2-\ell^2-a\ell+a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}}$$
$$=\frac{2a^2-a\ell-\ell^2}{\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}}=\frac{(2a+\ell)(a-\ell)\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}}{(a-\ell)(a+\ell)}=\frac{(2a+\ell)\sqrt{a^2-\ell^2}}{(a+\ell)}$$
which matches what you got.

I'm not sure where you got the factor of $a^4$, I think it should just be $a$. And where is the dependence on $\ell$ in the original problem.

@Nic Thanks, it was an error. Hopefully fixed now

Thanks@J.Chapman I have two queries. What did you do with the $sec^2\theta$ term and shouldn't the $\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a}$ term be +ve?. Also plugging in a and l in your result yields $\frac{a(l+2a) + l^2}{\sqrt{a^2 - l^2}}$  and not the result mentioned in the question. Perhaps,I am missing smething?

@Argentum I added some details. I had left off the $\sec^2(\theta)$ because it wasn't the hard part :)

Thanks @J.Chapman . I should have been a little more persistent with my own effort after your initial answer. All doubts cleared (y)

I would simplify first:
$\displaystyle
\int_{l}^{a}\frac{a^3-x^3}{(a^2-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}dx = \int_{l}^{a}\frac{a^2+x\,(a+x)}{(a+x)\,\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$
Where I used
$(a^3-x^3) = (a-x)\,(a^2+ax+x^2)$
Then we can compute:
$\displaystyle \int\frac{a^2+x\,(a+x)}{(a+x)\,\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx = \int \frac{a^2}{(a+x) \sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx+\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx$
The second integral is just: $- \sqrt{a^2-x^2} +C$ and for the first one I think you can solve it by substituting $x =a \sin u $. I am not sure if it is faster than the answer you already received though.

A bit shorter
$$I=\int\frac{a^3 - x^3}{(a^2 - x^2)^{\frac 32}}\,dx$$
$$x=a\tanh(t) \quad \implies \quad \frac Ia=\int \Big(\tanh (t)\,
   \text{sech}(t)+\frac{\text{sech}(t)}
   {\tanh (t)+1} \Big)\,dt$$
$$\frac I a=-\text{sech}(t)+(\sinh(t)-\cosh(t))$$  Now, back to $x$ using $t=\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$ and the bounds.
